# PartialView Navigation not returning parameters

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've setup a partialview to handle navigation throughout multiple views.  Some of these views use a different model so I'm passing that model in like this

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Navigation/_PartialTabs.cshtml", new xxx.OpenAccess.OBProfiles())
```

It load up my partialview just fine

```
@using xxx.Helpers;

@model xxx.OpenAccess.OBProfiles
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li role="presentation" class="@Html.IsActive("Edit", "OBProfile")">@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "OBProfile", new { id = Model.ProfileID }, null)</li>
<li role="presentation" class="@Html.IsActive("Index", "OBProfileTasks")">@Html.ActionLink("Tasks", "Index", "OBProfileTasks", new { id = Model.ProfileID }, null)</li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
```

However when I mouse over the links, the parameters (Model.ProfileID) return 0 regardless of what screen i'm on.  So the tab URLs look like this `http://localhost:55129/OBProfileTasks/Index/0`

What am I missing that it isn't returning the `/Number` of whatever profileid ive selected?

Comment: By passing new xxx.OpenAccess.OBProfiles() to the partial as a "new" object, the ID will always default to 0. Unless you are populating it in a constructor.

Comment: Is there a way to pass the model into it without always returning 0 in the razor view?

Comment: Since the only thing you use is the ProfileId value, unless there is more code, I would just make your model an int and pass that in.

Comment: Does the page using the partial have a Model? is it xxx.OpenAccess.OBProfiles?

Comment: Yes the pages using the partial have a model.  It changes depending on page though.

Comment: Somehow you need to populate the properties of xxx.OpenAccess.OBProfiles. you can create a static method that returns an instance of OBProfiles, or you can fill the properties by adding a default constructor to OBProfiles.

Comment: @TheDizzle are you populating OBProfiles in a controller method somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepopulate OBProfiles. Here are two ways:

Constructor:

In the OBProfiles class add:

```
public OBProfiles(){
ProfileID = *some value*;
}
```

Static method:

```
public static OBProfiles GetProfiles(){
return new OBProfiles{ProfileId = *Some value*};
}
```

The for static method call:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Navigation/_PartialTabs.cshtml", OBProfiles.GetProfiles())
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe TheDizzle hit the nail on the head. When you pass the model in as new, you're passing in a clean version of that model. Try just passing the model in without using the new keyword.

Comment: Passing a model without the new keyword will throw an exception unless you are calling a static method.

Comment: And it wasn't the Dizzle that said that, it was me.

Comment: Sorry for the mix up on the names. I was under the assumption that the view that's calling the partial view was passing the OBProfiles object to it.